# Beginners's Confusion about Model-to-World coordinates mapping

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d

As we know OpenGL maintains  modelview and projection matrix for mapping points .

If look closely,I divide the modelview matrix to:
mat4 modelview = WorldViewMtx * ModelWorldMtx

Well,**what I don't understand is how the ModelWorldMtx calculate out**

For example,if we have model corrdinates(MC) and world coordinates(WC) in 2D ,as showed below :
[image: MC And WC]

The point in MC a=[1;1;1] (column vector in homogeneous coordinate ,I express it the way like in Matlab ),mapped to the WC is b = M*a=[-1 0 4;0 1 3;0 0 1]*[1;1;1]=[3;4;1], I take M as a transition matrix between two coordinates (I mean,the relation matrix between base vector of the two coordinates ).

If we apply gltranslate(1.0,0.0,0.0) in 2D style,then the translate matrix is T =[1 0 1.0;0 1 0.0;0 0 1]. So point a will mapped to WC in this way:

b' = M*T*a=[-1 0 4;0 1 3;0 0 1]*[1 0 1.0;0 1 0.0;0 0 1]*[1;1;1]=[2;4;1].

So in this example,what exactly the ModelWorldMtx is ?

In my view,Affine transformation functions like glTranslate,glScale is just work in model coordinates.If the MC and WC are not coincide in this case ,

so ModelWorldMtx =M*T=[-1 0 4;0 1 3;0 0 1]*[1 0 1.0;0 1 0.0;0 0 1]= [ -1 0 3;0 1 3;0 0 1].

If the MC and WC are coincide in OpenGL,the transition matrix M is an identity matrix,so ModelWorldMtx = T,that is to say after calling gltranslate the point is mapped to WC .

Am I right ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? "So in this example,what exactly the ModelWorldMtx is ?" It is whatever you define it to be. You just did the composition of 2 transformations and got the result which should be expected. But I don't understand what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As we know OpenGL maintains modelview and projection matrix for mapping points.

Actually as of OpenGL-3 it doesn't. The built-in matrix stacks have been deprecated and removed from OpenGL-3.3 core and later.

> If look closely,I divide the modelview matrix to:
>
> ```
> mat4 modelview = WorldViewMtx * ModelWorldMtx
> ```

Nope, the modelview matrix is just

```
mat4 modelview
```

It doesn't separate into submatrices naturally. Of course you can compose a homogenous transformation matrix by multiplying a number of matrices in succession, but the result then is just a single matrix.

When glTranslate, glScale or similar are called they are effectively replacing the current M with the result of multiplying that very matrix with a translation, scaling or such matrix.

> Am I right?

Not quite. You're largely overthinking this. The transformation process in the old fixed function OpenGL pipeline is

```
pos_view = M · pos_local
pos_clip = P · pos_view

pos_clip'_0…1 = clip(pos_clip_0…1)

pos_NDC = pos_clip' / pos_clip.w
```

That's it. There's nothing more fancy going on. OpenGL is rather dumb. Of course these days we're doing everything with shaders and the first two lines in the segment above can be anything that can be expressed in a turing complete language.